# If $b \in (-\infty, \infty)$ in $z=a+bi$, then how to mark the range of $z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

Let $a$ be fixed.

If $b \in (-\infty, \infty)$  in $z=a+bi$, 
then how to mark the range of $z$?

Comment: What do you mean by "mark"? Does something like $\Re(z)=a$ ([real part](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RealPart.html)) satisfy you?

Comment: @Wojowu is there a way to notate that similarly to how one'd notate image of $a+b$ like $(-\infty, a] \cup [a, \infty)$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: So you want to find a way to denote the set of $z$ like in the question? In that case, you can use $\{a+bi:b\in\Bbb R\}$.

Comment: @mavavilj: I'd say that Wojowu's characterization of the set is typical: $\{z \mid \Re(z) = a\}$.  One sometimes sees merely $\text{Re}(z)$ for $\Re(z)$.